# Searched option doesn't works in lower and upper cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a search option in my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/46wyH/33/

so I have a value (`value` is the searched text).

I search all of the li that contains the value: `value`

```
// hide all the lists
$('#searchExcludeResult li').each(function() {       
      $(this)[0].style.display = "none";
});

// show all the li that contains the value: value
$('#searchExcludeResult li:contains(' + value + ')').each(function() {       
    $(this)[0].style.display = "list-item";
    $(this)[0].innerHTML = $(this)[0].textContent.replace(value, 
                                '<span style="font-weight: bold">' + value + '</span>');
});
```

it works, but I want it to work no matter the searched text is in lowercase or uppercase.

for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>United States</li>
    <li>London, England</li>
    <li>Moskow, Russia</li>
</ul>
```

and the searched text is: `e`, show the first (unit **e** d stat **e** s) and the second li (London, **E** ngland).

the searched text can be `EN`, `eN`, `l`, `L`, etc..

any help appreciated!

Comment: Try this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/

Comment: no, this jsfiddle shows the result (the searched text is the letter `e`).

Comment: As answers said you can convert to lower/upper case but do not forget this has internationalization issues (for example uppercase of "i"  is not "I" in Turkey). If you do not mind then go happy with that (but use lower case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `.contains` filter to be case insensitive or create your own selector.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
 return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

<kbd>[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/46wyH/34/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4Hzz6/1)

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and match [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) `.text()`.

```
$('#searchExcludeResult li').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}).each(function () {
```

Comment: thank you very much! but it doesn't work if I searched the letter 'E'

Comment: @AlonShmiel check --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4Hzz6/1/ .Changed `.indexOf(value)` to `.indexOf(value.toLowerCase())`

Comment: now it doesn't work: value = "eN";

thank you for your time! `Unknown` solved my problem.. thanks!